# Keybindings respond very slowly

Tags: dbus, wayland

Unity, Ubuntu 16.04.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to show the terminal, it appears after about 7 to 20 seconds.

How I've ended up like this: installed `gnome-session-wayland`, `dbus-user-session`, `nvidia-370`, launched GNOME-X session several times and also tried to launch a GNOME-Wayland session a lot (that was the goal). Also, I was rebooting and logging into Unity randomly throughout the process.

Haven't touched any configs. Removing wayland stuff doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, removing wayland stuff and rebooting helped. It has eaten the splash screen however (fix for splash: `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-*`, reinstall `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`, `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`).